# Signtool error : No certificates were found that met all the given criteria

Tags: signtool

I can see all the valid certificates and they haven't got expired but all of sudden everybuild started failing on Failed to sign error in Jenkins. We are just using MSBuild and provided pfx and thumbprint in CSProject.

I've tried to grant access to user admin access to fetch the certificates.
 Tried to debug and found 
After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

I don't get how all of sudden something has changed to the certificates and even there is nothing in the event logs.

Comment: Try adding more tags to expand your questions exposure. I also have the issue with UWP and if you solved this please let us know here. -Thanks.